# strange error with RCassandra trying to store the "iris" dataset

Tags: sql, r, cassandra, database, nosql

I am new to Apache Cassandra. I installed the R extension [RCassandra](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCassandra/index.html) and created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE iris (
    id varchar, 
    "Sepal.Length" double, 
    "Sepal.Width" double, 
    "Petal.Length" double, 
    "Petal.Width" double, 
    Species text, 
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

After successful connection and keyspace selection I try the following:

```
> RC.write.table(c,'iris',iris)
```

The `iris` dataset has the following form:

```
> iris
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
...
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in RC.write.table(c, "iris", iris) : 
    Cassandra exception: Not enough bytes to read value of component 0
```

Maybe the `id` field is troublesome, so I created the following dataset by adding an `id` column to the dataframe:

```
iris2 = data.frame(id=row.names(iris),iris)

iris2
     id Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1     1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2     2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
3     3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
4     4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
...
```

but I still get the same error:

```
> RC.write.table(c,'iris',iris2)
Error in RC.write.table(c, "iris", iris2) : 
  Cassandra exception: Not enough bytes to read value of component 0
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I have not used RCassandra, but you might try changing the column names to avoid the period, e.g. Sepal.Length -> sepal_length. I know some other tools have problems with that, even thought it's technically valid in CQL/Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating the column family ("table") in Cassandra using CQLSH?  Was myself having the same problem.  Then switched to using cassandra-cli and created the column family the [this way](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/tools/use_create_table_t.html), and it worked.

Most likely RCassandra uses cli underneath, and because CFs created in CQLSH are not visible in cassandra-cli, it can't see CQL tables.

Comment: I am not using anymore `RCassandra` since it's outdated (compatible with a previous version of Cassandra). Now I am using `rJava`/`DBI`/`RJDBC`, everything works. Then, of course, column names need to be conservatively lower-case and without strange characters, as the dot